# Akka 2.6 Actor Discovery In A Non-Actor Class (Get ActorRef Outside ActorSystem)

Tags: java, akka, akka-typed

I am working with Akka at the moment I have the following protocol.

[image]

In my protocol I have a server that is only responsible for creating resources (room and gabblers). These resources are created and then accessed. Next, I would like by means of a key to find the corresponding Gabbler ActorRef to send a message but this time from a class that exposes an API / method that is not an actor. I have seen the documentation and it is incredible to me that there is not a method in the actor system that can return a specific actor from its hierarchy to use it. I have already read the Receptionist section and although it is not very clear to me, I see that it is again oriented to the actors. There is no method in Akka that returns the reference based on the path of the Actor?

```
package co.test;

import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.typed.javadsl.AskPattern;
import akka.actor.typed.receptionist.Receptionist;
import co.test.actors.ChatServer;

public class ChatServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ActorSystem<ChatServer.ServerCommand> system = 
            ActorSystem.create(ChatServer.create(), "chat-server");
        
        system.tell(new ChatServer.NewEventRoom("room1"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user1"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user2"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user3"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user4"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user5"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user6"));
        system.tell(new ChatServer.AttendeeJoin("room1", "user7"));
        
        //ActorRef<Gabbler.Command> gabbler = get specific Gabbler ActorRef
        //gabbler.tell(new Gabbler.SendMessage("test");
    }
    
}
```

The protocol in the image above is already implemented but I am stuck in understanding what was asked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for getting data from actors to outside of the actor system (e.g. the `main` method), you're dealing with the [ask pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-from-outside-an-actor).  When using the ask pattern, you'll need to design your message protocol to support it, typically by having messages that are intended to be asked having an `ActorRef<ReplyMsg>` field (often named `replyTo`).  `akka.actor.typed.javadsl.AskPattern.ask` effectively creates a short-lived actor, injects the `ActorRef` of that actor into the message, and if it gets a message within a timeout period, it completes a `CompletionStage` with that message.

In  this application, since you're routing everything from `main` through the `system` actor, you could define a `ChatServer.GetAttendee` message:

```
// assuming that there's an interface Command {} already in ChatServer
public class ChatServer extends AbstractBehavior<ChatServer.Command> {
  public static class GetAttendee extends Command {
    public final String room;
    public final String user;
    public final ActorRef<ChatServer.AttendeeIs> replyTo;

    public GetAttendee(String room, String user, ActorRef<ChatServer.AttendeeIs> replyTo) {
      this.room = room;
      this.user = user;
      this.replyTo = replyTo;
    }
  }

  public static class AttendeeIs {
    public final ActorRef<Gabbler.Command> ref

    public AttendeeIs(ActorRef<Gabbler.Command> ref) {
      this.ref = ref;
    }
  }
}
```

(the `ChatServer` would likely pass the message on the corresponding `ChatRoom`)

In your `main`, you would send the ask with something like

```
String desiredRoom = "whatever";
String desiredUser = "whoever";

CompletionStage<ChatServer.AttendeeIs> getGabbler =
  AskPattern.ask(
    system,
    replyTo -> new ChatServer.GetAttendee(desiredRoom, desiredUser, replyTo),
    Duration.ofSeconds(15),
    system.scheduler()
  )

 CompletionStage<ActorRef<Gabbler.Command>> gabblerFuture =
   getGabbler.thenCompose(
     (ChatServer.AttendeeIs response) ->
       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response.ref)
   )

 ActorRef<Gabbler.Command> gabbler = gabblerFuture.toCompletableFuture().get()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Levi for responding. I understand the approach to solve my question. But I see that the ask pattern is synchronous which in the end hinders the optimization of the asynchrony offered by the tell pattern. As I am just new to the Akka tool kit, it has not been easy for me to move forward in a smooth way. I was looking at two possibilities to solve the question asynchronously:

Comment: 1. With the receptionist I could generate a hash in which to identify each of the Gabblers and through a message that includes their ID the Receptionist would route it (I don't know how optimal be). 2. I have realized the importance of Streams, seeing them now as the tool par excellence to work reactively and seeing the actors as resources to achieve it, this has cost me but I would have to investigate much more to achieve a solution. Levi what do you think of these two approaches? Or do you think I have to use the ask pattern?

Comment: Lastly Levi, excuse me for asking so much. With the ask approach, the main actor (chat server) would be a discovery actor of all the actors, if there were too many different actors, the main would be very heavy. Suddenly you know why if there is a unique identifier for the actors such as the path, there is not simply a Map and a method that will return the actor's reference?

Comment: Ask is only synchronous to the extent that you block waiting for the response: i.e. you do as much as you can in callbacks on the futures.

Comment: Using the receptionist is no different in practice than routing messages through the main actor.  It introduces a choke point.

Comment: As for streams, chances are you're going to use the ask pattern when interacting with actors from the stream (in order to have backpressure).

Comment: If I was designing this, I'd actually have `NewEventRoom` be an ask with the response containing an `ActorRef<ChatRoom>` and then send the `AttendeeJoin` messages to the `ChatRoom` actor (with them supporting ask), but that's a more substantial redesign.

Comment: Thank you very much Levi, I understand I will continue then first practicing with the ask pattern.

Comment: Can you please provide some example of ask pattern including receptionist with Java language?